# Query - Does Not Contain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a search query to lookup Customers.

I would like to use the Sounds Like function to return additional possible results, however this is returning some of the same results in my main search query.

I would like to only show the additional results in a partial view.

I basically need a DoesNotContain.

Here is what I have so far for my main query:

```
customer = customer.Where(c => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.CustomerID).Trim().Equals(searchString)
                          || c.CustomerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

And for the additional results:

```
customeradditional = customeradditional.Where(c => SqlFunctions.SoundCode(c.CustomerName.ToUpper()) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

The only possible solution I can see at the minute is to do a Contains Query, loop through each item and get the IDs, then do another query for CustomerID != 1 or CustomerID != 2 or CustomerID != 3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
customeradditional = customeradditional
    .Where(c => SqlFunctions.SoundCode(c.CustomerName.ToUpper()) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(searchString.ToUpper()))
    .Except(customer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood you correct:

From what you have now, the `customeraddtional` query does return some of the customers already returned in the `customer` query. And you only want the results, which are not already contained in the customer query.

Then the solution would be:

```
 customeradditional = customeradditional.Where(c =>  
                         SqlFunctions.SoundCode(c.CustomerName.ToUpper()) == 
                         SqlFunctions.SoundCode(searchString.ToUpper()))
                                        .Except(customer);
```

This way your are explicitly excluding every item, which is present in the customer object.

Comment: Thanks Serv. Also the correct answer. BartoszKP just beat you to it by 15 seconds.

Comment: Nullo problemo. Feel free to upvote every answer you feel worth it in addition to mark the correct one ;)